# If $\mathrm{rank}{(A - \lambda I)^k} = \mathrm{rank}{(B - \lambda I)^k}$ then $A$ is similar to $B$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Let $A,B \in M_n(\mathbb{C}).$ Suppose for all $\lambda  \in \mathbb C $ and for all $ k\in \mathbb Z_{+} $ we have $\mathrm{rank}(A - \lambda I)^k = \mathrm{rank}(B - \lambda I)^k.$ Then why are $A$ and $B $ similar?

Comment: Are you sure you want to limit $A,B$ to _real_ matrices? Since in general the spectrum will have complex values in it (any only considering the real spectum would make the assertion false), the ranks you are computing are those of complex matrices in any case, so you might as well let $A,B$ be complex to begin with. The only real [no pun intended] effect of having $A,B$ be real is that you are probably (implicitly) asking for $A,B$ to be similar by a _real_ change of basis (but it is a general fact that if the are similar over the complexes, they will be similar over the reals).

Answer (score 2):

Let $J^n_\lambda$ be a Jordan block of size $n\times n$ with $\lambda$ on the diagonal. Then $\mathrm{rank}(J^n_\lambda - \lambda I)^k=n-k$ for $k\leq n$ and otherwise it is zero.

If we now take $A=J^n_\lambda \oplus J^m_\lambda $ with $m\leq n$, then you will get that $\mathrm{rank}(A - \lambda I)^k=m+n-2k$ for $k\leq m$ and for $m\leq k\leq n$ you will get that $\mathrm{rank}(A - \lambda I)^k=n-k$.

In general, if $A$ is a sum of $d$ Jordan blocks (with eigenvalue $\lambda$), then 
$$\mathrm{rank}(A - \lambda I)^k-\mathrm{rank}(A - \lambda I)^{k+1}$$
is the number of block of size at least $k$, hence this numbers determines $A$.

Since $\mathrm{rank}(J^n_\lambda - \eta I)^k=n$ for $\eta \neq \lambda$, this can be generalized to arbitrary Jordan blocks. And finally, since the rank is invariant under conjugation, this is true for every matrix.

Answer (score 0):

The Jordan theorem says that if $\sigma(A)=\sigma(B)$ and, for every $k$ and every $\lambda\in\sigma(A)$, $\mathrm{rank}((A-\lambda I)^k)=\mathrm{rank}((B-\lambda I)^k)$, then $A,B$ are similar.

It is equivalent to prove that the Jordan normal form of a given matrix is unique up to the order of the Jordan blocks. For an idea of the proof, read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form

In fact, the complete proof is a long way. Read a book; it's your business!

About your question, we must prove that $\sigma(A)=\sigma(B)$; the reason why is that the generalized eigenspaces of $A$ span whole $\mathbb{C}^n$ and, consequently, the generalized eigenspaces of $B$ associated to $\sigma(A)$ span also whole $\mathbb{C}^n$.